# Oracle "DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL" using question

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ddl

Using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL question

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE', 'PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT', 'TEST') was used to output the procedure and function DDL

1. When using double quotes when creating for the first time

CREATE PROCEDURE "TEST"."PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT"

ex.SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE', 'PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT', 'TEST') FROM DUAL;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TEST"."PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT"
~~

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE "TEST"."RESULT1"
BEGIN
    NULL;
END

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE','RESULT1','TEST') FROM DUAL;
```

RESULT1.

```html
    CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "TEST"."RESULT1"
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END
```

2.When first created
CREATE PROCEDURE PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE', 'PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT', 'TEST') FROM DUAL;

ex. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TEST"."PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT" PCD_TBL_BLOB_INSERT
~~

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE RESULT2
BEGIN
    NULL;
END
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE','RESULT2','TEST') FROM DUAL;
```

RESULT2.

```html
    CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "TEST"."RESULT2" RESULT2
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END
```

Even if you create it like result 2, I want result 1

oracle version :  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: Don't understand what do you want from your example. So the difference between result 1 and result 2?

Comment: result 1 : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SCHEMA"."OBJECTNAME"

result 2 : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SCHEMA"."OBJECTNAME" OBJECTNAME

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of code, instead write that code out in a code block (enclosed with single backticks for inline code and triple backticks for blocks).